# Controlling screen and window size in Unity

Tags: unity, screen

In Java I know how to make a window of a certain size and make it not resizable.

How do I control my game's window size in Unity and prevent players from resizing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the size your game is displayed in the editor window- have you customized the settings in the game preview window? If the game window of your editor is set to 'free aspect' or a resolution other than what is intended, the preview in the editor might not be an accurate reflection of what size your game window will be in your final build. If the desired size is larger than the size of your editor you'll want to click 'maximize on play' as well.

In terms of defining a set size for your game window though, if you go to 'File', then 'Build Settings', click 'Player Settings' and then under 'Resolution' un-check the box that says 'Default is Full Screen', you can set a default height and width for your player. You'll also want to un-check 'Display Resolution Dialogue' to avoid the user changing the resolution when the game first launches, and the 'Allow FullScreen Switch' box to prevent the player from switching to full screen mode using OS specific short cuts.

You can also set the screen resolution in your code with '[SetResolution](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html)'.

If you are interested in scaling your game for multiple screen sizes though, take a look at the following sections of the Unity API- [Designing for Multiple Resolutions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html), [Canvas Scaler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html).